# ErrorJSX' s not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I installed typescript to existing folder.
I got a special error

```
error  'JSX' is not defined no-undef
```

There is my imports in this file

```
import React from 'react';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { defineFeature, DefineStepFunction, loadFeature } from 'jest-cucumber';
import { render } from 'configs/jest/testUtils';
import AppNavigation from 'src/components/AppNavigation';
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: You should provide more information. For example: on what system are you installing typescript? How do you try to install it (command)? 

Giving more specific info, will get you a better answer sooner

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no JSX in typescript. Try to change the .jsx to .tsx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).